# FCM Message statuses statistics not showing in Play Console

Tags: firebase, google-play, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I linked my Firebase Cloud Messaging API key to my application on Google Play last week to get access to the statistics.

While I can see statistics for FCM Registrations I'm unable to see any data for FCM Messages?

Is this a case of just waiting longer or is there some additional step besides adding in the API key for FCM?

Comment: By statistics, do you mean the analytics on the Firebase Console?

Comment: Already deprecated. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this Play Console Help [article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en), the FCM diagnostics and statistics data has already been removed from the Google Play Console since last November 30, 2017.

You may, on the other hand, try to reach out to the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) team to check if there's any other tool that you can use, or if they're building a new tool related to this.